# "Outlook is closing" in Notification Tray - Can't reopen without killing the process

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, process, microsoft-outlook-2016, outlook-addin

I have received a few notes that outlook isn't closing properly and only after a reboot it is possible to re-open outlook.
A day after, I noticed the same thing on my computer.
So basically, what I found out is, that after closing Outlook, the process isn't shutting down properly, and in the notification tray appears the typical grey outlook symbol called "Outlook is closing". But it won't close until you kill the process.

Now I read a few threads in different forums, where people had the same issue in older Office versions, but none is really identical to mine. So I'm stuck right now... anyone any advice?

**OS**:      *Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit*

**Office**:  *365 (Outlook 2016)*

**Add-Ins**: *Zimbra Connector, Agile PLM but disabled(!)*

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Some add-in or program that integrated into Outlook and uses Outlook data may be the cause.

Comment: This happens all the damn time, it's four years later. I can't believe I actually paid for this software.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue. Without disabling the add-ons, the following steps worked for me:

```
1) Hit Control-Alt-Delete
2) Click Task Manager
3) Go to 'Users' Tab
4) Under User name (usually an email address), expand/collapse all the programs. 
5) Search for Outlook.exe and 'end' the process by using Left click of the mouse.
```

This will kill the process altogether and you should be able to restart Outlook with a click.

Comment: Works as expected -> Outlook 16.0.14131

Comment: In my case it was under `Microsoft Outlook`.

Comment: Normally I go to Task Manager, Processes and kill the task associated with Outlook, then I go to Task Manger, Services and restart "ClickToRunSvc". This time, only your suggestion worked. Also, like in Bram's case, it was not "Outlook.exe" but "Microsoft Outlook".

Answer (score 5):

This issue is mostly caused by add-ins. Try to run Outlook in safe mode first: `outlook.exe /safe`. If this mode allows it to exit properly, then disable your add-ins one by one to find the falty one. After that contact the add-in's developer.

Answer (score 2):

## What worked for me: cancel sync before closing outlook

### Background

I've tried the following:

1. Tried safe mode. Issue still occurs in safe mode
2. Removing all addons. Issue recurrs.

### What worked

1. Click on the send/receive button in the status bar
   [image: send/receive in status bar]
2. Click on "Cancel All" button
   [image: Cancel all]

### Interpretation

- I'm guessing some sync tasks are getting stuck. When you close outlook, the program is stuck waiting for the sync tasks to finish.
- Maybe, I (or you) should fix the issue causing the sync to get stuck

Comment: you saved 10 hours of work. thank you very much!!!

Answer (score -3):

I had the "outlook is closing" error. Nothing could help. Finally removed battery. It reset and has worked ever since.